# Problema hacer Click en un menú drop CSS

Tags: html, css

Tengo un ligero Problema con el menú cuando hago Clic en él se quita y no me envia a la direcion que esta en el Link como puedo hacer que funcione?

```css
.onclick-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #444442;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 14px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 6em;
  /* padding: 5px 0 0 9px; */
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-align: center;
}

.onclick-menu:before {
  content: " ";
}

.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
  display: block;
}

.onclick-menu:focus .dropdown-caret {
  display: block;
}

.onclick-menu-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 205px;
  color: #313030;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 18%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: -webkit-left;
  padding: 12px 0 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.onclick-menu-content li span {
  color: #66757f;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.onclick-menu-content li span:hover {
  background: #e6e7ea;
  color: #313030;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.onclick-menu a.text_topbar_span:hover,
.onclick-menu-content span.text_topbar_span:hover {
  background: #475fa5;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu">
  <span class="text_topbar_span">Menu</span>
  <div class="dropdown-caret">
    <div class="caret-outer"></div>
    <div class="caret-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
    <a href="./page/useterms">
      <li><span>Términos de Uso</span></li>
    </a>
    <a href="./page/pivate">
      <li><span>Política de privacidad</span></li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu problema está en el `display:none`.. si lo quitas funciona correctamente

Comment: @MiguelAngelGonzalezPinto no

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si lo elimino, si funciona correctamente.

Comment: @MiguelAngelGonzalezPinto un link no necesariamente tiene que llevar .html,.php, otros para funcionar, el seo funciona sin seo

Answer (score 0):

Un `<ul>` debe tener como hijos `<li>`, al encapsular el `<li>` dentro de un `<a>` estás provocando que el **DOM** se vuelva un poco loco.

Una sintaxis más apropiada sería:

**HTML**

```
<div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu">
  <span class="text_topbar_span">Menu</span>
  <div class="dropdown-caret">
    <div class="caret-outer"></div>
    <div class="caret-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
    <li>
      <a href="./page/useterms">
        <span>Términos de Uso</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./page/pivate">
        <span>Política de privacidad</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

De esta manera deberían de funcionarte los enlaces correctamente.

Comment: si tienes razon lo que deces, pero no funciona en esta codigo el problema esta en el css, como yo no sé mucho de css por eso pido ayuda

Comment: Nota aún no funciona

Comment: El problema lo estás teniendo con esta regla **CSS**: .onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
  display: block;
} En el momento en el que el botón "Menu" pierde el foco el submenu se deja de mostrar. En el momento de hacer click en otro elemento, como un item del submenú, el submenú desaparece por lo que te quedas pinchando el aire. Ocurre muy rápido pero es por eso por lo que no se llega a producir la redirección del enlace. Para hacer la prueba quita el **display: none** de .onclick-menu-content en tu CSS para que se quede siempre desplegado el submenú.

Comment: tienes razon y como hago que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de arreglar esto es mediante **[JQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)** de la siguiente forma, debido a que como te explico bien el colega **PHPMyguel** hay inconsistencias al utilizar `display: none` para esconder tu submenú

```js
$('.text_topbar_span').on('click', function(){
   $('.onclick-menu-content').css('display','block');
})
```

```css
.onclick-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #444442;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 14px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 24px;
  width: 6em;
  /* padding: 5px 0 0 9px; */
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-align: center;
}

.onclick-menu:before {
  content: " ";
}

.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
  display: block;
}

.onclick-menu:focus .dropdown-caret {
  display: block;
}

.onclick-menu-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 205px;
  color: #313030;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: 18%;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: -webkit-left;
  padding: 12px 0 6px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.onclick-menu-content li span {
  color: #66757f;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.onclick-menu-content li span:hover {
  background: #e6e7ea;
  color: #313030;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.onclick-menu a.text_topbar_span:hover,
.onclick-menu-content span.text_topbar_span:hover {
  background: #475fa5;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu">
  <span class="text_topbar_span">Menu</span>
  <div class="dropdown-caret">
    <div class="caret-outer"></div>
    <div class="caret-inner"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
    <li>
      <a href="./page/useterms">
        <span>Términos de Uso</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="./page/pivate">
        <span>Política de privacidad</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ignoro si estás utilizando esta librería en tu proyecto pero te serviría para no perder el estilo de tu `css` y al mismo tiempo conseguir la funcionalidad que necesitas.

Sin embargo, si necesitas trabajar exclusivamente con `CSS`, esperaría la respuesta de otro colega más instruido en diseño :)

Comment: ya funciona el link pero ahora se queran activados y no se quitan

Comment: Crea un ejemplo y publicalo para entender y poder ayudarte :)